# communication between R shiny modules deployment problem

Tags: r, shiny, deployment

I have question about communication between R shiny modules.  I used golem package develop an app with two modules: data and analysis https://xuemaozhang.shinyapps.io/reactivedata/
To share a data set I used reactiveValues, values = reactiveValues(data_imported=NULL) in app_server.R.

After I deployed the app to shinyapps.io, I found that it does not allow multiple users: when one user changes the data, other users will see the same updated data as well.   I am new to shiny app development.  How the problem can be solved?   The source code can bee seen from my github site: https://github.com/xuemaozhang/reactivedata

Comment: Have you tried put `values = reactiveValues(data_imported=NULL)` in the function app_server ? I think the fact you initialized it in global.R make it persistent between users. If you initialize it in the app server, it should be distinct for each user

Comment: The app wont work if  "values = reactiveValues(data_imported=NULL) " is in the app_server function.  When I put it outside of the app_server function, same thing happens.  Is it possible to create a temporary data folder for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `mod_module1_data_server`, `mod_module2_analysis_server` and the `app_server` function in order to work with data in-session, no need to create a `reactiveValues()` outside of the server function:

```
mod_module1_data_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    # ns <- session$ns
    Data <- reactive({
      Data <- get(input$dataset)
      Data
    })
    output$datatable<-renderDataTable({ Data()  })
    return(reactive(Data()))
  })
}
```

```
mod_module2_analysis_server <- function(id, Data){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    observe({
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "numvar",
                           choices = names(Data()))
    })

    output$summary <- renderPrint({
      summary(Data()[, input$numvar])
    })

    output$histogram<- renderPlot({
      hist(Data()[, input$numvar])
    })
  })
}
```

This is what you should put on server:

```
server <- function( input, output, session ) {
  Data <- mod_module1_data_server("module1_data_ui_1")
  mod_module2_analysis_server("module2_analysis_ui_1", Data)
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  The problem is solved!   I'll keep the original files on web so others have the same problems with modules can see it.

Comment: If it is solved, please mark my comment as the right answer, thank you